# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'; RequestFactory

Tags: python, django

I'm testing a view `UserProfilePage` with a mock request object using `RequestFactory`. An error is being raised when invoking the `GET` handler; saying a positional argument is missing. Yet there are not positional arguments within the request. What would be raising this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1201, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "C:\..\authors\test\test_views.py", line 110, in setUpTestData
    request = RequestFactory().get(reverse("authors:profile", kwargs={'id': 1}))
  File "C:\..\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\..\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

```
class TestViewUserQuestionsPostedPage(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user("ItsMe")
        viewer = get_user_model().objects.create_user("ItsYou")
        request = RequestFactory().get(reverse("authors:profile", kwargs={'id': 1}))
        cls.view = UserProfilePage.as_view()(request).view_class
        cls.view_context = cls.view.get_context_data()

    def test_viewed_profile_of_user(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(self.view, Page)
        self.assertIn('user', self.view_context)
        self.assertEqual(self.view_context['object'], self.user)
```

```
class Page(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['search_form'] = SearchForm()
        return context



class UserProfilePage(Page, SingleObjectMixin):

    model = get_user_model()
    pk_url_kwarg = "id"

    def get(self, request, id):
        return HttpResponse("Hi")
```

```
authors_patterns =  ([
    path("<id>", av.UserProfilePage.as_view(), name="profile")
], "authors")

urlpatterns = [
    path("users/", include(authors_patterns, namespace="authors"))
]
```

Comment: What is reverse doing?

Comment: You write `UserProfilePage.as_view()(request)` but your view also expects an `id` as an argument. `UserProfilePage.as_view()(request, id="1")` should be what you should write

Answer (score 0):

In your authors_patterns path you have `<id>`.  You haven't specified that the id should be an int, eg `<int:id>`

In your reverse you are passing a kwarg that is an int.

```
kwargs={'id': 1}
```

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/) it specifies that:

> Captured values can optionally include a converter type. For example,
> use `<int:name>` to capture an integer parameter. If a converter isn’t
> included, any string, excluding a / character, is matched.

Could it be that, because you are not passing a string, it isn't being matched?

Try specifying your url as `<int:id>` or your kwarg as `kwargs={'id': '1'}` and see if that solves your problem.